# I am a violent storm.. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, sports

I belong to the rider's heel.

Someone might think of wrestling, but I am not from there.

I am a violent storm.

But above all I am a sportsperson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you mean

> Harry Kane
>  , a footballer (sportsman) who plays for Tottenham Hotspur (riders heels)

Comment: was this too easy ? :/ I'll ask a hard one next time :)

Comment: I think I was just lucky to "guess" the storm and the riders heels and then had the answer.

Comment: Could also probably mention that the 2nd line (wrestling) refers to the wrestling character Kane. And the 'violent storm' refers to a 'hurricane'.

Comment: @SlashmanX , exactly.

Comment: I got the hurricane, that is how I found him. I have no idea about wrestling, though. ;-)